# Plotting Datetime Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a python program in which i read a csv file onto a Pandas dataframe. Then I  want to plot my sensor value with datetime in a clean format. My code gives error **ValueError: time data ' 2017/02/17' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f**. 
My Code and some rows from dataframe is below:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime
    import csv
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    headers = ['Sensor Value','Date','Time']
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users\Lala Rushan\Downloads\DataLog.CSV', parse_dates= {'Datetime': [1,2]},names=headers)

    print (df)

    df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%y/%m/%d , %H:%M:%S.%f"))
    #datetime.strptime(df['Datetime'],"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    x = df['Datetime']
    y = df['Sensor Value']

    # plot
    plt.plot(x,y)
    # beautify the x-labels
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

    plt.show()
```

DataFrame:

```
                      Datetime  Sensor Value
0     2017/02/17  19:06:17.188             2
1     2017/02/17  19:06:22.360            72
2     2017/02/17  19:06:27.348            72
3     2017/02/17  19:06:32.482            72
4     2017/02/17  19:06:37.515            74
5     2017/02/17  19:06:42.580            70
6     2017/02/17  19:06:47.660            72
```

How can i solve this error? I'm newvie to python so pardon any basic mistakes.

Comment: It's telling you that your date doesn't match the format string. The question is why the error says the date string is `"2017/02/17"` but your posted dataframe looks like it should be `"2017/02/17  19:06:17.188"` (also note no comma) or similar.

Comment: yes thats what i am thinking and stuck at. can you tinker the code to work?  I am new to python.

Comment: Just use `pandas`'s datetime parser: `df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])` insteading of trying to use `map` to parse each row value. This should parse the entire field into `datetime` if the format is consistent all throughout.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to split date and time. Below code works well for me.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')
print (df)

df['Datetime'] = df['Datetime'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))

x = df['Datetime']
y = df['Sensor Value']

# plot
plt.plot(x,y)

# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: this code gives the same error for me. maybe theres the difference in the **read_csv** part where i am parsing the date and time into one column. do you think there might be a problem there?

Comment: How can we modify the code so that the part after seconds are not shown (all those zeroes). Also, how can we make it to show until minutes let's say?